# How to get class name only, not full path?

Tags: android

I am aware that using `Context` and a method `getClass().getName()` I can get a string which represent full class name, like `com.package1.package2.MainActivity`.

How can I get only the last part, class name only? In this case it would be `MainActivity` string.

I can do it with a simple `split()` method, but maybe there is a better way, more reliable.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

This is all you need.

```
MainActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Comment: This is the right thing. The `getLocalClassName()` will return any package name within the root of the app. This returns class' name only, no matter if it's in root or in some other package.

Answer (score 22):

To get only the name of the class, not full path you will use this expression:

```
String className =  this.getLocalClassName(); 
//or
String className = getBaseContext().getLocalClassName();  
//or
String className = getApplicationContext().getLocalClassName();
```

Comment: Every day is a school day, nice find :-)

Comment: Yes, I hate for being so soon after I posted a question, but it's better I posto it this way than to delete a question.

Comment: do not rely on both 3 if you on old API, null or useless text will return. For me only getClass().getName() works

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you could use:

```
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

Answer (score 3):

1. If you need class name within a method, use `getLocalClassName()`
2. If you need class name outside a method, use `getClass().getSimpleName()`
3. If you want to reuse the class name in multiple methods within the same class, then use `private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();` within the class and then use TAG variable in every method.
4. If you want to access the class name from static methods, then use `private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();` now use the static variable TAG within your static methods.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what way you do it, you'll need to perform an extra operation on top of getClass. I'd recommend this over split:

```
String className = xxx.getClass();
int pos = className.lastIndexOf ('.') + 1; 
String onlyClass = className.substring(pos);
```

Comment: read last line of his post he wants other then split(substring)

Comment: That's fine, I didn't use split.

Comment: @Rawkode There is a better way. This one is more secure than using `split` or `substring`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getSimpleName` method:

```
String name = getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin you should use:

```
val className = javaClass.simpleName
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin way: `MainActivity::class.java.simpleName`

Answer (score 0):

No other solutions work for me, dunno why. I'm using

```
this.getClass().getName().replace("$",".").split("\\.")[3]
```

cons: in one string, and you can use it in threads and listeners.

(in listeres I get something like *com.djdance.android.main$53*)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the name outside the class you can call:

```
MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()
```

in this way you can avoid to make your class static.